# Why the height is incorrect?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0

I have a simple WPF form with next XAML

```
<Window x:Class="ReikartzDataConverter.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="650" Width="800">
    <Grid Width="780" Height="650">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="500"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Content="Process information" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,20,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="235" />
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Width="780" Height="500" Name="paysTable">            
        </DataGrid>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" Height="28" Name="lblError" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden" Foreground="OrangeRed" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="12" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Quit" Height="23" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        <Button Grid.Row="3" Content="Start" Height="23" Name="button2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button2_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Why my 2 buttons from Grid.Row="3" are partially located out of the visible part of the window?

My window has the height="650" and my Grid also has the Height="650"
I have 4 Rows: 50, 50, 500, 50. So the last row must be located inside the window. Why is not so?

Answer (score 2):

The Window Height of 650 also includes the 'chrome', i.e. the bar at the top of the window with the minimize, maximize buttons. It is a much better approach to create a layout which does not rely on a specific height. In your case, I would make the row that contains your grid auto-sized:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Then you can remove the height / width from your Grid, and all your other UI elements, just let the grid dictate the size of its children.

Comment: Thanks! And if the Grid reaches the height = 800. Does the grid add vertical scroll automatically or the grid lays the buttons row?

Answer (score 2):

@ColinE's answer is the right approach in that you should adopt a "fluid" layout in WPF, but if you really want a fixed height for your content and you need the window to be the right size, you can use the [SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.sizetocontent.aspx) property:

```
<Window x:Class="ReikartzDataConverter.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Width="800"
    SizeToContent="Height">

    <Grid Width="780" Height="650">
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Setting SizeToContent to "Height" will make the window resize vertically so that its contents fit. Don't forget to remove the Height property from the Window declaration.